# NoclassDefFoundError exception while running android app

Tags: android

im new to android and i have a prob in ksoap2 jar . im getting the following exception while running the program and the program closes with error- unfortunately the app stopped. im using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies for the jars and i have included it both in the build path lib and also in /lib folder but still the problem persists.

im using the .zip file i dont kno how to convert it to jar ... is this the prob. please help , thanks in advance .

```
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.example.ksoap2demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-04 06:24:38.337: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Make sure that you have defined your class in .manifest file.Also place some code.Place .rar file to your lib folder

Comment: A very common problem. Use libs instead of lib if your using ADT17+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem which i can for see is rename the folder to libs instead of lib. and if you unzip the .zip file you will probably get the jar file and that jar file you need to put in the libs folder and add in the build path. that will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out external jars such as

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

to be put under /libs folder so Eclipse ADT automatically adds your jars to the buildpath of your application. It was a buildpath missing defined class error after all.. I hope this will help you, too!